# How to impose interface?

Tags: c++

How I should make sure that classes needed as a one of params to my templated class will have a certain interface? I know that one way is to make in Interface class pure virtual but I would like to avoid it. Is there any other way to do it?  I would like to avoid anything which isn't standard

```
    //Example  
    template<class SomePolicy>  
    class My
    {
void fnc()const
{
SomePolicy::mustHaveThisInterface();//<--here I have to have  
// this interface in orded to work

}
    };
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by interface? Do you just want to be guaranteed that the class defines a `void mustHaveThisInterface()` function? Or is it required to override the specific `virtual void mustHaveThisInterface()` defined in some predefined base class?

Comment: then the answer is "just try to compile the code". The compiler will reject it if the function isn't defined. :)

Comment: What does "I would like to avoid anything which isn't standard" mean? A lot of things are standard and not part of a library. Do you mean you would prefer some mechanism that is part of the (possible future) standard library?

Comment: @Andre Caron yes you're right, again!;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to have a dummy function that validates the requirement. Example:

```
class Interface {};

    // Basically a no-op, but has to compile.
template<typename I, typename T>
void require ()
{
    T * t = 0; I * i = t;
}

template<class SomePolicy>
class My
{
    void fnc () const
    {
            // won't compile unless `SomePolicy` inherits `Interface`.
        require<Interface, SomePolicy>();
    }
};
```

Note that, since this is a template, `My<T>::fnc()` won't be compiled unless it is called, which  means your validation `require<I,T>()` directive must be placed somewhere important (e.g. the constructor, or at the beginning of each function where `SomePolicy` must inherit `Interface`.) Just how many checks you put depends on your level of paranoia.

**Performance Note**: since the check amounts to a no-op, any decent compiler will optimize it out so it won't cost anything in run time or memory.  The compiler is still obliged to make it compiile though, which means it can't skip the test at compile-time.

Comment: Caron I like this approach very much. Just to make sure I understand this correctly - the check is made based on the fact that pointer of Base class can be assigned to a pointer to a Derived class, isn't that so?

Comment: You understand it correctly, but it's the other way around, the pointer to the derived class can be assigned to the pointer of a base class!

Answer (score 4):

The question is what you mean by "interface". If you just want require the class to contain certain methods, simply use these methods. If the class given to the template doesn't have them, you will get a compilation error if you try to instantiate the template with that class.

It will only compile if all the methods you try to use actually exist.

Comment: I agree with sth. A while ago a colleague introduced me to Eiffel where it was possible in the language to include constraints that a template type parameter inherit from a specified type. While this may seem helpful it removes one of the principle freedoms of templates. That you may use any appropriate type regardless of how it fits with your inheritance hierarchy. Insisting that the type parameter inherit from a particular class may bite you later when you wish to use a class that you cannot control for that parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Stroustrup wrote about solutions for this. Check [here](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#constraints) and [here](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/N1522-concept-criteria.pdf).

Comment: +1 for referencing the dude that started it all. Doesn't get much better than that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you mean by 'interface', the code you posted may already do the job:

```
//Example  
template<class SomePolicy>  
class My
{
    void fnc() const
    {
        SomePolicy::mustHaveThisInterface();
        // this interface in orded to work
    }
};
```

this code will fail to compile if `mustHaveThisInterface()` is not defined on the `SomePolicy` class. So you are *already* guaranteed that the policy class has the correct interface.

If instead you wish to ensure that `SomePolicy` derives from some interface class which defines a virtual `mustHaveThisInterface`, then you could use `std::is_base_of` from the `type_traits` header added in TR1 (and previously available from Boost):

`std::is_base_of<MyInterface, SomePolicy>::value` will be true if and only if `SomePolicy` is derived from `MyInterface`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use type_traits and SFINAE to guarantee that SomePolicy inherits from an interface.

```
template<typename T> class My {
    typedef typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_base<
            T,
            some_interface
        >::value,
        bool
    >::type __traits__impl; // Won't compile if T does not inherit from interface
};
```

Comment: @DeadMG could you please give some example or maybe some link with example? Thank you.

Comment: @DeadMG is it what Andree is talking about?

Comment: @There: No. I'll post an example.

Comment: @DeadMG but isn't is_base using the same technique desribed by Andre? And could you please explain how it works step by step? I'll be more than grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Although this uses standard library code, it always amazes me how 1) it is more painful to write than a hand-crafted solution; and 2) that it genrates totally unreadable messages upon misuse compared to a simple "cannot convert `T*` to `I*`". The real benefit though, is that you have a better guarantee that it works out of the box!

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: `std::enable_if` takes a compile-time evaluated boolean condition to determine which type to instantiate. If the condition evaluates to false, a `std::enable_if<Condition,T>::type` is a `typedef` for a type that cannot be instantiated preventing compilation. In this case, the condition is `std::is_base<T,U>` which is related to my solution, but produces a compile-time `false` rather than generating a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

Boost has a library called [Concept Check](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm) for just this use. It can be used to ensure that any type parameter to a template has the minimal features required for operation of that template. It comes with checks for all of the standard library interfaces, plus shows you how to write your own for interfaces you invented.

Comment: almost like stroustrup ;), thank you for your answer. I forgot to add in my original post that I would like to avoid anything which isn't standard. I'll update my post.